# Change element width based on innerWidth property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change an element's width.

```
<p class="bg-primary" style="width: 100px;" id="test"></p>
```

The script successfully takes the screen width...

```
let x = window.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
```

...and halves it...

```
let halfx = parseInt(x * 0.5);
```

...and parses it into a string.

```
let elemWidth = '"' + String(halfx) + 'px"';
```

However, the code then fails to update the style.

```
document.getElementById("test").style.width = elemWidth;
```

Any clues?

Comment: what's the actual `elemWidth` value? Have you tried logging in console?

Comment: You are adding quotes to `elemWidth`. Just do `let elemWidth = halfx + "px"`; (you also don't need to parseInt the value if multiplying it *first* works; I suspect you wanted to do `parseInt(x) * 0.5`) final note: you can just do `....width = "50%"`

Comment: Why go through all the trouble when you could simply use `width: 50vw` in CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your code was doing double string causing it to fail. If you had `console.log(elemWidth)` would have told you `""158px""` or something like that.

```js
let x = window.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;

let halfx = parseInt(x * 0.5);

let elemWidth = halfx + 'px';

document.getElementById("test").style.width = elemWidth;
```

```html
<p class="bg-primary" style="border: 1px solid black;" id="test">TEST</p>
The script successfully takes the screen width...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help;  I had been trying to get an image to scale in IE11.  100% width was not recognising the width of the parent element.  At: https://github.com/haymanjoyce/compactGantt-Web